# Select cells in ElseIf Not Intersect *** Is Nothing Then

Tags: excel, vba

This line is working in my VBA Macro:

```
ElseIf Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("$M$3,$Q$3")) Is Nothing Then
```

I want to convert the cells to a named range, ie:

```
ElseIf Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("Sk_Iron").Cells(3, 1)) Is Nothing Then
```

where the named range is entire columns M to Q. That line works

But I want both cells to activate the Sub, ie:

```
ElseIf Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("Sk_Iron").Cells(3, 1),Cells(3, 5)) Is Nothing Then
```

Can this be done and what is the syntax?
Thanks, Neil.

Comment: It is done by using [Application.Union](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union): `ElseIf Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Union(Range("Sk_Iron").Cells(3, 1), Range("Sk_Iron").Cells(3, 5))) Is Nothing Then`. Could you share more relevant code, I mean that line is pretty long and you should consider using variables to make the code more readable. Also, using `ActiveCell` may not be correct if this code is used in an event procedure.

Comment: `Range("Sk_Iron").Range("A3, E3")`

Comment: Both work but I like Vitalizzare's answer as it is more readable. Thanks for both answers.